# ASP.Net Server.Transfer and Hiddenfield

Tags: asp.net, hidden-field

I try to save on Onclientclick to my hiddenfield a string value but it doesnt work I think because of Server.Transfer();

In my is only one control for postback(Dropdownlist) if I change dropdown value I get work Server.Transfer at last in my code.

Here is the code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    alert($("[id*=hdnSelectedDiv]").val());
});

function SaveDiv(value) {
    $("[id*=hdnSelectedDiv]").val(value);
}

   <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CssClass="card-link" ID="lnkGoToLogin" OnClientClick="SaveDiv('dvLogin');return false;" meta:resourcekey="lnkGoToLoginRes"></asp:LinkButton></p>
```

Here is my OnSelectedIndexChanged :

```
   CurrentSession.SetCurrentLanguage(ddl.SelectedValue);
        ddl.SelectedValue = CurrentSession.CurrentLanguage.IetfLanguageTag;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(ddl.SelectedValue);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(ddl.SelectedValue);
        Server.Transfer(Request.Url.AbsolutePath);
```

On document ready alert is my value always empty.I try to set value on my document and alert the value it is working.but if I click linkbutton and select any option in my dropdown after postback is my value empty.

How can I solve this I dont want to use Response.Redirect();

Comment: No matter what you use, a postback has still occurred and the page will refresh, meaning you need to re-populate anything in the DOM that you set manually. If you don't want that, you can look into using [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) (AJAX) to make requests without navigating away from the match.

Comment: I don't understand exactly , I want only get value from hiddenfield after postback.Before postback I save my value in my hiddenfileld.Why should I need re-populate manual ?

Comment: Because you are transferring to another page. Whether you redirect or transfer is irrelevant. You're going to get a new page either way, with a fresh DOM.

Comment: I understand you now :) You have right ..How can I hold the value ,  have you any suggest for this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That hidden field must have `name` property.

When the postback occurs, within the server code, is the moment when you can retrieve posted values. This is the time to process them - because, after `Server.Transfer` starts executing, source context is gone. If you need those values within the target request (the handler transferred to), you need to pass them to it. Your options are: persisted storage (e.g. database), session (might be the best in your case), query.